# Semaphore minimization

Tags: multithreading, semaphore, monitor

I stumbled upon a problem in a multi-threading book in the library and I was wondering what I would need to do in order to minimize the number of semaphores.

What would you do in this situation?

[Semaphores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6k1n.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume a process **P0**'s execution depends on other *k* processes: **P1**,...,**Pk**.
You need one semaphore to synchronize the processes and to satisfy this single constrain.

The semaphore **S0** is initialized with 0, while **P0** will try to wait *k* times on **S0** (in other word, it will try to acquire *k* resources).

Each of *k* processes **P1**, ..., **Pk** will release **S0** upon their ends of executions.

This will guarantee that **P0** will start execution only after all the other *k* processes complete their execution (in any order and asynchronously).

In the link you provided, you need 4 semaphores, **T1** does not need any semaphore because its execution depends on nobody else.